# Monotouch: Downgrade to 3.2.6 (More Stable) Version

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, downgrade

Since MT 4 version still has some bugs for WCF services, I would downgrade it to 3.2.6.

I've recovered this old version but now it doesn't work because I have a more recent mono-framework version. What steps do I have to follow for disinstalling mono-framework 2.10.1_3 and recovering the old one?

Thank you. Regards.

**Update:** For those interested in, rembember to uninstall previous mono version. See this link: [Uninstall Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX#Uninstalling_Mono_on_Mac_OS_X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old mono-framework will recognize, that you are installing an older version over an newer one and prompt you to continue

Comment: Thank you for your reply..I would reinstall 2.10 mono-fr. Where can I find this version? Thanks.

Comment: But for MT 3.2.6 i would rather choose mono 2.6.7

Comment: Thank you Karl. I'll try to fix it. Regards.