# What's currently more stable - Monodroid or Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have to port a windows 6.5 app to both Monodroid and Monotouch. Now the question is which one to tacke first. I've taken some first steps with Monotouch, but encountered several blocker stability issues. It appears that version 4.0x is [currently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493660/monotouch-downgrade-to-3-2-6-more-stable-version) really production-ready, and older versions of Monotouch are only available for registered users. Monotouch support claims they are working on the issues, but I need to work on this now. Ultimately I will have to buy both, but after the bad experience I've had so far I'd like to be sure I am not wasting my money and implement the app first.

Now I am wondering - Should I implement the Monodroid app first and then return to Monotouch? I was going to wait until there is at least one book on Monodroid available at Amazon, but if Monodroid was at least stable enough for production, I might give it a shot before this happens nevertheless.

So in the end it comes down to the question whether the latest release of Monodroid is significantly more stable than the latest release of Monotouch. If you have tried both, what do you think?

Comment: MT is much more mature than MD.  MT has been in release over a year, and I've used it for two apps.  Not saying it's perfect, but I think it's much more stable than MD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MT is much more mature than MD. MT has been in release over a year, and I've used it for two apps. Not saying it's perfect, but I think it's much more stable than MD.

Answer (score 0):

The SO question you link to seems to just be a problem someone was having with WCF. I don't know what the bug is/was, but if you aren't planning on using WCF it would seem irrelevant.

That said, a new MonoFramework was just released today (2.10.3) which contains a lot of fixes (especially for MacOS Lion) and a new MonoTouch (4.0.4.1) was released ~2 weeks ago which fixed many of the more critical issues people have had with MonoTouch since May.

I'd suggest you try the MonoTouch trial and see if it works for you. If not, we'd love to get feedback on what is broken for you and/or where we can improve your experience with MonoTouch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand and appreciate your effort to improve Monotouch stability. At the same time, there are still quite a few threads here on SO quotiing all kinds of critical bugs (not just WCF). However, I did not ask this as a rebuke against Monotouch or Monodroid. I'm probably going to create apps on both systems in the end, so you can I'm not opposed to them at all. My question was merely which of the two frameworks is currently more stable.

Comment: Understood. In that case, I'd say MonoTouch is probably a lot more mature/stable. Again, we would appreciate any feedback on bugs you find and/or ways we can make MonoDevelop, MonoTouch, and Mono for Android even better (I'm sure there's a looooong list, but we want that list anyway!)